# Not able to connect to my aws eks cluster getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

after setting up my cluster tried to connect to my cluster. test everything is fine. but getting below error.

command i executed:
kubectl get svc

Error i get:

Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in scheme "pkg/client/auth/exec/exec.go:62"

Answer (score 0):

Related to this

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1210.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920.

Try updating your `aws-cli` and `kubectl`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured for me after I upgraded my local Docker Desktop to latest version 4.12.0 (85629). As this version was causing problems while running kubctl commands to update my feature branch Hoard image, I did following steps to resolve them.

1. I updated my local config file under C:/Users/vvancha/.kube by replacing v1alpha1 to v1beta1
2. And I took the latest version of k9s from https://github.com/derailed/k9s/releases . I took the latest as of now is  https://github.com/derailed/k9s/releases/download/v0.26.7/k9s_Windows_x86_64.tar.gz
3. I updated my AWS CLI to latest of CLI2 version by command in my local
4. Run cmd, msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
   confirmed that my version is aws-cli/2.8.3 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
5. I updated my STS client pointing to my required role
6. Run command to update kubernate
   aws --region us-east-1 eks update-kubeconfig --name dma-dmpreguse1 --alias dmpreguse1 <change as per your need
7. Open your k9s and Verify it .
   Now I am able to update my required changes.